# How to get the confidence of svm algorithm in sklearn using python

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, svm

I want to get the confidence but when I try `clf.score(X_test)` I get the following error:

> TypeError: score() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

This is my code:

```
import cv2, os
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import RandomizedPCA
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC

cascadeLocation = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadeLocation)

def prepare_dataset(directory):
    paths = [os.path.join(directory, filename) for filename in os.listdir(directory)]
    images = []
    labels = []
    row = 140
    col = 140
    for image_path in paths:

        image_pil = Image.open(image_path).convert('L')

        image = np.array(image_pil, 'uint8')
        nbr = int(os.path.split(image_path)[-1].split('.')[1])
        print(nbr)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(image)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            images.append(image[y:y+col,x:x+row])
            labels.append(nbr)
            cv2.imshow("Reading Faces ",image[y:y+col,x:x+row])
            cv2.waitKey(50)
    return images,labels, row, col

directory = 'dataset'
directory2 = 'dataset2'
images, labels, row, col = prepare_dataset(directory)

n_components = 10
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
pca = PCA(n_components=n_components, whiten=True)

param_grid = {'C': [1e3, 5e3, 1e4, 5e4, 1e5],
              'gamma': [0.0001, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.1], }
clf = SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced')

testing_data = []
for i in range(len(images)):
    testing_data.append(images[i].flatten())
pca = pca.fit(testing_data)

transformed = pca.transform(testing_data)
clf.fit(transformed,labels)

image_paths = [os.path.join(directory2, filename) for filename in os.listdir(directory2)]
la=[]
for image_path in image_paths:
    pred_image_pil = Image.open(image_path).convert('L')

    pred_image = np.array(pred_image_pil, 'uint8')

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(pred_image)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        temp=np.array(pred_image[y:y+col,x:x+row]).reshape((1, -1))

        X_test = pca.transform(temp)

        id = clf.predict(X_test)
        #a=clf.score(X_test)            
        if(id==1):
            id="john"
        elif(id==2):
            id="brad"
        elif(id==3):
            id="scr"
        elif(id==4):
            id="natalie portman"
        elif(id==5):
            id="jennifer lawrence"
        elif(id==6):
            id="van diesel"
        elif(id==7):
            id="jennifer aniston"
        elif(id==8):
            id="leonardo dicaprio"    
        else :
            id="unknown"
        print(id)               
        cv2.imshow("Recognizing Face", pred_image[y: y + h, x: x + w])
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also tried `clf.score(X_test,id)`. In this case all confidence takes the value `1.0`.

Comment: This is not the svm from opencv, but from sklearn

Comment: @jakevdp can you help me ??

Comment: I might have misread your question the first time. I edited my answer to better suit what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.decision_function) (emphasis mine):

> **`decision_function(X)`**
>        Predict **confidence scores** for samples.
>        The confidence score for a sample is the signed distance of that sample to the hyperplane.

You have to change `a=clf.score(X_test)` to `a = clf.decision_function(X_test)` in your code.

**EDIT**

I'm guessing you actually wish to "manually" validate your model by checking whether `dataset2`'s images are recognized or not. In that case you need to introduce a number of changes in your code:

- Put his sentence at the very beginning of the outer `loop`loop:

  ```
  nbr2 = int(os.path.split(image_path)[-1].split('.')[1])
  ```

  I'm assuming that the file naming conventions for `dataset2` are the same than those for `dataset1`, otherwise you would have to redefine `nbr2` accordingly.
- Don't use `id` as a variable name since `id` is a reserved word in Python. You could use `idx`instead:

  ```
  idx = clf.predict(X_test)
  ```
- Replace the compound `if-elif-else` statement by a dictionary (outside the `for`loop):

  ```
  names = {1: "john",
           2: "brad",
           3: "scr",
           4: "natalie portman",
           5: "jennifer lawrence",
           6: "van diesel", 
           7: "jennifer aniston",
           8: "leonardo dicaprio",
           }
  ```

  and change `print(id)` to `print(names.get(idx, "unknown"))`.
- And last, replace `a=clf.score(X_test)` by `a = clf.score(X_test, nbr2)`.